# System hangs when I try to debug this javascript method for @Html.Dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a HTML DropdownList for which I have an onchange event. But When I put a debugger in the method, it just crashes my system on execution. Any ideas as to where the problem is?

```
@Html.DropDownList("abc", new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text", @selectedValue), new { @class = "aoDropDownListWidth", @onchange = "ShowTextBox();" })

function ShowTextBox() {
    debugger;
    var TextBoxObject = document.getElementById("xyz");
}
```